# Impersonating list of users with Google Service Account

Tags: google-oauth, gmail-api, google-identity

According to the docs, Google Apps domain administrators can grant service accounts domain-wide authority to access user data on behalf of users in the domain. My understating is this gives service account authority to access data for **all users** inside the domain. Is there a way to restrict which users service account has access to?

For example, an application that uses Google Calendar API to view events from the calendars of specific list of users in a Google Apps domain.

Can google apps administrator authorize application for access to some but not all users?

Thanks

Comment: did you ever find a way to restrict access for the service account to only some users?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to publish an app in [Google Apps Marketplace](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/overview). An app can be turned ON for everyone or some specific organization unit. See [Turn a Marketplace app on or off for users](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172931?hl=en&ref_topic=1056395). Organization Unit is how you can control who in organization has access to your app.

Comment: Isn’t a marketplace app a public app, though? What if I just want a private application to use a service account to access one or two users’ accounts and be forbidden to access any other users’ accounts?

Answer (score 0):

If you're an administrator, yes. You can control who uses any particular Google service from their account. Just turn the service on or off for those people in your Google Admin Console. When users sign in to their account, they see only those services that are turned on for them.

To delegate domain-wide authority to a service account, first enable domain-wide delegation for an existing service account in the Service accounts section of the Developers Console Permissions page or create a new service account with domain-wide delegation enabled. Your application has the authority to make API calls as users in your domain(to impersonate users).

Here's a useful material for Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: The idea is not to turn off "Google Calendar" service for some users. I was asking about restricting an application which uses Service Account access to say Calendar API for specific users. I can't find any way in Google Admin Console to control API client access per user.